# How to Join Table with JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, entity

I have four tables.

**ZipCode**

zipCode(PK)

townCode

**Town**

townCode(PK)

townName

cityCode

**City**

cityCode(PK)

cityName

prefectureCode

**Prefecture**

prefectureCode(PK)

prefectureName

I want to get all parameter only searched by *zipCode*.
Now ,I wrote this code.

```
@Entity
public class ZipCode extends GenericModel {
@Id
@Column(length = 7, nullable = false)
public String zipCode;
@Column(length = 8, nullable = false)
public String townCode;
@ManyToMany(targetEntity=Town.class)
@JoinTable(name="town")
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="townCode",insertable=true,table="town",name="townCode")
public Set<Town> towns;

@Entity
public class Town extends GenericModel {
@Id
@Column(length = 8, nullable = false)
public String townCode;
@Column(length = 255, nullable = false)
public String townName;
@Column(length = 5, nullable = false)
public String cityCode;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="townCode")
public Set<ZipCode> zipCode;
```

and I execute this,

List zipcodes = ZipCode.find("zipcode = ? ", zipcode).fetch();

TableStatus is,

**ZipCode**
zipCode(PK) | townCode
1111111     | 123

**Town**
townCode(PK) | townName | cityCode
123          | tokyo    | 12345

I want get all parameters, but response only have ZipCode status...

Please tell me ,How to get all parameter.

Help me!

Comment: Have you defined entity classes for City and Prefecture ? What do u mean by all parameters ?

Comment: Sorry,City and Prefectureis not defined yet.

Comment: all parameters is 

zipCode
townCode
townName
cityCode
cityName
prefectureCode
prefectureName

these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you have defined a mapping between zipCode and Town , you need to provide a mapping between Town and City and also between City and Prefecture .

Once you have done that , you will be able to fetch all the towns for a zipcode and from the town you will be able to get the City and from the City , you will be able to get the Prefecture 
Moreover looking at your tables , I don't see a Many to Many relationship between Zipcode and Table , So you might consider changing it to Many to One

```
public class Zipcode {
// all the other attributes 
// Provide the mappings via annotation
public Town town ;

}

public class Town {
// all the other attributes 
// provide the mappings via annotation
public City city ;
}

public class City {
// all the other attributes 
// Provide the mappings via annotation
public Prefecture prefecture ;

}

public class Prefecture {
// all the other attributes 

}
```

And finally

```
List zipcodes = ZipCode.find("zipcode = ? ", zipcode).fetch();
foreach(Zipcode zip : zipcodes) {
  zip.getTown() // to get the town 
  zip.getTown().getCity() // to get the city 
  zip.getTown().getCity().getPrefecture()  // to get the Prefecture 
}
```

It is advisable to go for Lazy loading if you are not going to use all the details everytime.

Comment: thanks Mr.Rocky!!

but i dont understand how to use annotation...
Could you tell me what annotation should I use ?

Comment: You can read up on how to use annotations for mapping entities here - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association                                                                    You need to use Many to One mapping

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Rocky!!JPA is so difficult for me...In this case(between ZipCode and Town), which is the owner ?

Comment: Dindt quite catch you , what do u mean by owner ?

Comment: Sorry,,,i mistake OneToMany for ManyToOne.

Comment: I guess you are new around here , once you get the answer you are looking for , accept that answer ,so that other people know about it when they are searching for something similar